# requests module slow because enconding

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

The module requests in python becomes so slow when trying to guess the encoding (atleast with encoding ISO-8859-1)

```
import requests
url = 'https://geoportal.minetur.gob.es/VCTEL/infoantenasGeoJSON.do?idCapa=null&bbox=-1.5525697885398,39.26519497205,-1.549179476345,39.273649294864&zoom=4'
r = requests.get(url)
```

This takes more than 2 minutes

```
import os
url = 'https://geoportal.minetur.gob.es/VCTEL/infoantenasGeoJSON.do?idCapa=null&bbox=-1.5525697885398,39.26519497205,-1.549179476345,39.273649294864&zoom=4'
url2 = url.replace("&", "\&")
os.system(f"curl {url2} > ./fast_answer")
with open("./fast_answer", "r", encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
    data = f.read()
j = json.loads(data)
```

This takes less than 1 second

I understand that `curl` could be faster than requests but 2 minutes against 1 second its too much. It's a problem from my side or is a `requests` bug?

Comment: I don't see these differences - both are pretty similar for me (amending the code so both versions write to disk).

Comment: Yep, thats the point. However, requests need 2 minutes for return response.
My thought is that requests is wasting 99% of the time guessing encoding

Comment: Does it still take 2 minutes if you replace print(r.json()) with print(r.content)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel yes, actually what it takes 2 minutes is only the request, im gonna edit it for avoid missconfusion

Comment: @snakecharmerb you mean, you tried it and on your side both take the same time?

Comment: For me, both take 0.3 - 0.5 seconds

Comment: @snakecharmerb which version of `python` and `requests` module are you using?

Comment: python 3.9 / requests 2.24.

Comment: i just updated to python3.9, same version of requests. However the requests takes 2 minutes yet. I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Both take less than a second here too. It must be something else that's skewing your timings.

Comment: i have been testing in another computers, and only 2 of them had that problem, i know for sure the 2 minutes are spend on the request line, but im not sure why as is not a problem of request but more a problem of my system, maybe something about computers network?? i dont have any idea

Answer (score 0):

If you still have that problem, you can also try urllib.urlopen(url):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  
url = urlopen('https://geoportal.minetur.gob.es/VCTEL/infoantenasGeoJSON.do?idCapa=null&bbox=-1.5525697885398,39.26519497205,-1.549179476345,39.273649294864&zoom=4')
print(url.read())
```

Regarding your "comparison question", the requests package tries to guess the encoding from the headers () and might be spending time on it. You could set it and check if it improves:

```
import requests
url = 'https://geoportal.minetur.gob.es/VCTEL/infoantenasGeoJSON.do?idCapa=null&bbox=-1.5525697885398,39.26519497205,-1.549179476345,39.273649294864&zoom=4'
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
print(r.text)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.